# Highchart Line and Range

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a Highchart Area range and Line but can't get it to work and i don't know why. Could anyone please help with what i'm doing wrong?
The range should be the same for every point so that i can see which points is out of range.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ew5e1fmy/12/

```
$(function () {
var ranges = [
[1469904515000,3.5,8],
[1469913442000,3.5,8],
[1469926631000,3.5,8],
[1469948933000,3.5,8],
[1469948992000,3.5,8],
[1469955600000,3.5,8],
[1469960654000,3.5,8],
[1469968200000,3.5,8],
[1469971155000,3.5,8],
[1469981536000,3.5,8],
[1469991978000,3.5,8],
[1469998800000,3.5,8],
[1470013200000,3.5,8],
[1470032477000,3.5,8],
[1470041051000,3.5,8],
[1470046907000,3.5,8]
],
var values = [
[1469904515000,7.4],
[1469913442000,13.8],
[1469926631000,6.2],
[1469948933000,8.6],
[1469948992000,8.6],
[1469955600000,7.9],
[1469960654000,4.1],
[1469968200000,10.1],
[1469971155000,10.1],
[1469981536000,6.1],
[1469991978000,10.2],
[1469998800000,13.2],
[1470013200000,14.3],
[1470032477000,6],
[1470041051000,13.4],
[1470046907000,4]
];
$('#container').highcharts({           

                xAxis: {
                    title: {text: 'Dates',align: 'high'},
                    type: "datetime",
                    allowDecimals: true,
                },
                yAxis: {min: 0,
                    allowDecimals: true,
                    title: {text: '',align: 'high'},
                    labels: {overflow: 'justify'} ,                                     
                    labels:{enabled: true},                

                },                   

                plotOptions: {                    
                    line: {dataLabels: {enabled: false, style: {fontSize: '8px'},                                           allowDecimals: true}}

                },               
                credits: { enabled: false },

                series: [{
                zIndex: 1, 
                lineWidth: 1, 
                name: 'BG', 
                allowDecimals:true, 
                data: ranges }, 
                { 
                name: 'Range', 
                data: values, 
                type: 'arearange', 
                lineWidth: 0, 
                linkedTo: ':previous', 
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                zIndex: 0 }]
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you accidentally linked the values to the wrong serie (range serie is filled with values array while the values serie is filled with the ranges array)

Comment: Felix is correct. Here is how it appears when the linked values are corrected: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/ew5e1fmy/15/